# Dojo 1.6 Drag and Drop 'Dnd' Error ( Source.xd.js (line 8) )

Tags: drag-and-drop, dojo, javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/ykNJ8/

This is a vanilla implementation from the CDN, developing on localhost. 
I cannot seem to find a consistent way to replicate it, but it seems to happen most while dragging items near the bottom of the list. The dragging tool-tip does not lock to the mouse, but rather gets appended to the bottom of the document, where is will not go away.

[image: Tool tip broken]

This persistent tool-tip reacts to continued attempts to use the dnd.

[image: Broken tool tip reacting]

I checked the error in fire-bug ie and chrome consoles and it always returns the same thing:

Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined   Source.xd.js:8
```

Firebug:

```
_a.getItem(_b[i].id) is undefined 
window[(typeof (djConfig)!="undefined"..._4.dnd.AutoSource(_3d,_3c);}});}}};});    Source.xd.js (line 8)
```

IE's was not nearly as helpful.

Please help folks! I created a stripped down version of my page in jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ykNJ8/

I tested it and the error does occur in fiddle.

Comment: I can reproduce on your jsfiddle example.

Comment: I just found a way to replicate it consistently. Drag one to the bottom, so you cursor pointer lines up with the bottom of the list. Then drag the same item up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heh, took me forever but I figured out your problem. The problem is that you are instantiating **two** dojo.dnd.Source's.
The first:  When you specify the dojoType attribute on your id='faq' div.
The second: When you are calling new dojo.dnd.Source(sortID).

The result is that you have constructed two widgets on the same div and they are fighting with each other.

Here's a fiddle that fixes the problem by only using the markup-driven widget:
http://jsfiddle.net/TtbPh/1/

Don't give up on Dojo widgets just yet! There is a fairly steep learning curve, but once you get it nailed down you'll wonder how you ever lived without them :)

Comment: While it got rid of the bug. This method does not allow me to trigger a function with onDndDrop. How can I get that to fire, without declaring a new Dnd object?

Comment: Bah, I broke the zebra-ing didn't I? The problem is that I incorrectly stated that dojo.dnd.Source is a widget. It is not, so it is not correct to access it via dijit.byId.  Here's a solution that removes dojoType from your 'faq' div and instantiates the dojo.dnd.Source in the JavaScript. By doing that, we have a pointer to the dojo.dnd.Source instance to connect to:

http://jsfiddle.net/NAgug/1/

Comment: Ha, not so fast! You can always add a jsId attribute to your markup to get a global reference. 
http://jsfiddle.net/GtAEQ/1/

I tend not to like that technique as it adds to the global namespace. 

When using widgets, things like dijit.form.Button, or your own custom widgets, it is possible to access the widget instance via dijit.byId('idOfElement'). The DnD stuff is a bit odd in that you can use dojoType, but you aren't actually creating true widgets.

Comment: @Dan Lee thumbs up for the awesome answer. The point is just use only one global object to hold that dojo.dnd.Source object. Thanks Dan that's very helpful !